# Using git to Track changes to dropbox?

Tags: python, git, version-control, dropbox

> Skip to the bottom for the TLDR.

**Issue:**

In our environment everyone uses Dropbox to collaborate the development of a large coding project.  It solves the problem of everyone keeping up to date on what everyone else has changed, and it also provides some simple versioning as to "whom changed what, and when".

What Dropbox does not provide, which is what I am looking for, is Git's awesome sauce, as far as versioning, blame, content diffs, etc

**What I am working with now:**

I am still using dropbox as our "version control, because the other "devs" probably won't be able to figure out git, *I know it's easy, but they hate change*.

In order for me to see, "what's really happening, and who's doing it", I am tracking the entire dropbox folder *for that project* using Git.

I have to manually commit every once in a while *on behalf of the other devs* in order to track what's happening with Git's awesome sauce.

**What I am looking for:**

Does anyone have experience with the environment I am stuck in?  I would like to find something that can notice a change in Dropbox, pull the username of who made that change using dropbox's API, and auto-commit the change to git.

I have not found any such solution, and have already begun writing an app in Python to do what I want, *I might have to host this on github and ask for help*, low on free time, and relatively new to Python.

I am able to pull the RSS feed from the dropbox API and parse out what the file was and who changed it, but am not far enough to hook it into a Git Commit, *should be trivial*.  I just don't want to reinvent any wheels.

> **TLDR:**
>
> I would like to automatically track changes that occur in a dropbox
>   folder, and have them Git Committed, including the name of the person
>   who changed the file in dropbox, using dropbox's API, or similar.  Likely using Python, but anything is welcome.

**Thanks in advance.**

Git Repo, in case you want to help!
https://github.com/haqthat/git-drop

Comment: I understand your situation, but you can probably see the dangers that exist in just committing automatically for every single file change. You lose a lot of Git's power that way.

Comment: @voithos sure that is a problem, but the alternative is usually *no* version control. Which is worse?

Comment: FYI: Google Drive supports versioning out of the box.

Comment: would you post your code here or anywhere else so we can see what is done? You can add TODOs to show where you have problems.

Comment: I'll throw what I have so far up in a bit.

Comment: @user1320237 [https://github.com/haqthat/git-drop](https://github.com/haqthat/git-drop)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, your team needs one week of git practice and then will benefit from a much more robust workflow. Don't try to automate commits. Thats leading down the road to hell.

Comment: clearly the problem is the result of user1582 not having enough authority to dictate how the team should go.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato You may be correct, slightly, although having a solution to this issue could benefit more people than just myself.

Comment: @haqthat I feel your pain. Love it, change it or leave it. I just don't think this auto commit approach will get you far.

Comment: @Christoph I think it will accomplish what I am looking to do.  I won't be using git to it's FULL potential, but it will definitely help when it comes to "blame".  Right now, we only know who modified a file and when, not **what** was in the modification.  This piece alone is priceless, as well as seeing who is most active etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you can host it on linux, how about using [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html)? Whenever a file is updated in the dropbox folder by dropbox sync, iwatch can run a python script when that happens to pull the user. Then use [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy/) to run the two git commands, `git add 'filename'` and `git commit -m "autocommit by system for user X changes"`.

Sure it isn't very pretty, but it will do the job, and it won't run unless there is an update.

Comment: I'm deciding between [pyintofy](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) and just hooking the RSS feed for updates to initiate the commit, this part is trivial, looking for something "more developed".

Comment: Did you also look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4? Its stable enough for something like this and writing a git handler on directory changes in the folder of your interest would be trivial. Or maybe you could just migrate to Google drive?

Comment: @haqthat thanks for the link to pyinotify. I didn't know it existed. I don't think you'll find anything "more developed" though. This falls pretty squarely into shell scripting territory and many scripts like this are "hacky" and don't get to the wider world.

Answer (score 1):

I have used dropbox as a git repo  following something on the lines of http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290743/using-dropbox-git-repository

So from that, the simplest way I can think of is:

1) **Init a repo** in your dropbox folder (This will auto-sync across everyone you share it with)

2) **Configure it** with a remote on github or your own git server if any. This way all changes across files and users will be tracked at the remote.

3) Write a script as a cron job that periodically commits from your local dropbox and then runs against the **remote git server** and **looks for deltas and revisions**. You can get that from Dropbox API ref starting here - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#revisions

4) After doing the above, you might want to include a call to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata which as per dropbox returns a hash that can be used to track changes and then call your polling script. As of now there doesn't seem like there is a way for dropbox to notify you of changes other than you polling  every few minutes to the remote.

```
hash Each call to /metadata on a folder will return a hash field, generated by hashing all of the metadata contained in that response. On later calls to /metadata, you should provide that value via this parameter so that if nothing has changed, the response will be a 304 (Not Modified) status code instead of the full, potentially very large, folder listing. This parameter is ignored if the specified path is associated with a file or if list=false. A folder shared between two users will have the same hash for each user.
```

Comment: Thought of this, but it's kind of out of scope for what I'm trying to do.  

I don't want to keep a git repo **IN** dropbox, I want a git repo **OF** dropbox.  

I didn't see anything in the Dropbox API that actually tells you **WHO** modified the files....

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could use pyintofy and equivalents to create a username.myfileextension every time a file gets changed on any users account. But you will need the code to run on the users box which is a problem I guess. And looking around, doesn't seem like Dropbox is keen on implementing this feature and their reasoning makes no sense - http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=50917

Comment: One way I can think of is to invoke a scraping client like beautiful soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that scraps the DOM on https://www.dropbox.com/<your path> to get the modified time and username which you can then check against your local copy to generate diffs. Bad way, but should work until they change the UI.